# Unauthorized to Write to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Im trying to write to mongo via mongoengine.

In my `/etc/mongod.conf` i have `auth=true`.
My user that I am connecting with is,

```
{
        "user" : "dbexample",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbOwner",
                        "db" : "dbexample"
                }
        ]
}
```

However I still get ,

```
>>> john = Employee(name="John Doe", age=25)
>>> john.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 394, in save
    raise OperationError(message % unicode(err))
OperationError: Could not save document (command SON([('insert', u'employee'), ('ordered', True), ('documents', [SON([('name', u'John Doe'), ('age', 25), ('_id', ObjectId('56bc94d1f1d55600445bd085'))])]), ('writeConcern', {'w': 1})]) on namespace dbexample.$cmd failed: not authorized on dbexample to execute command { insert: "employee", ordered: true, documents: [ { name: "John Doe", age: 25, _id: ObjectId('56bc94d1f1d55600445bd085') } ], writeConcern: { w: 1 } })
```

EDIT : 
Heres the Django Mongo config,

```
_MONGODB_USER = 'dbexample'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = '####'
_MONGODB_HOST = '172.17.0.1'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'dbexample'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = 'mongodb://%s/%s' % (_MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)
```

Note : If I turn auth off I can write to the DB fine.

Comment: Please post the code in which you make mongoengine authenticate to mongodb (should be during or shortly after connecting).

Comment: How you connect to the database? It says you are trying to save to `dbOwner` database.

Comment: Sorry typo as i stripped out the actually db namings

Comment: Additional details added.

Comment: Do you authenticate against the correct database?

Comment: yer i checked and it looks like i am.

Comment: Have you try `mongo dbexample -u dbexample -p '####'` from command line to test whether connect to `dbexample` successfully?

Comment: Do you have this in your .conf file?    security:    authorization: enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-855 the problem might be in the connection string, try changing:

```
_MONGODB_USER = 'dbexample'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = '####'
_MONGODB_HOST = '172.17.0.1'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'dbexample'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' % (
           _MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mongodb connection string should include the user and password, see connectiong string format https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

```
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = 'mongodb://%s/%s' % (_MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)
```

should be

```
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = 'mongodb://user:password@%s/%s' % (_MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)
```

detail see: http://code.withlovee.com/?p=288